# Possibility to clear log in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

i am currently working on a big test suite, runtime > 8h. 
The longer Selenium is running, the slower it becomes. If i clear the log in Selenium it is back to full speed again. Is there any possibility/command to clear the log in Selenium itself?
I dont really need the log for reviewing the run.

I already worked through half of the internet, but all i could find was clearing the Browser history with Selenium. 
Would be great if someone could help. Even a confirmation that it is not possible would be helpful, then i could stop searching for a way.

Thanks!

Comment: when you say clearing the log, do you delete the log files or clear the log from where?

Comment: i clear the log in Selenium itself.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was also driving me crazy. I don't have a solution but I believe I found a workaround. (This works for me on Windows 10 using Firefox.)

Select the Reference "tab" (next to the Log "tab") and then start your testing. It appears that displaying the log messages causes the slow down problem. (You might notice that the log display stops showing new entries after some time, even though the log is still recording.)

You might try switching between Log and Reference to see if this workaround solves your problem (in your environment).

Answer (score 0):

I also have same problem like you and I've solved it by using **AutoIt**. And now **Selenium IDE** runs faster. **AutoIt** is another automation tool. I made a very tiny program with **AutoIt** which only clicks the '**Clear Log**' button of **Selenium IDE** after certain duration of time. The only negative side is, if there is any error on **Selenium IDE**, still log will get cleared after given duration of time. But it is still helpful if you are good at **Selenium IDE** and you don't need to know at which point **IDE** failed. Here is my **AutoIt** code:

```
$i = 0
Do
    Sleep(60000)

    WinActivate("Selenium IDE - Your project name goes here","Chrome Legacy Window")
    MouseClick("left",568,604,1)

Until $i = 1
```

Here is screenshot:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UxRX.png)

My **AutoIt** code actually clicks at a certain position but before that it activates the **Selenium IDE** window and it does not cause any problem to run Selenium IDE execution. Because it just clicks the 'Clear Log' button.